# Canvas not rendering as expected on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

I have this game I wanted to integrate to my website as a competition for my members. I took a source code of github https://github.com/daleharvey/pacman.

I didn't mess with a code. It works fine on local machine, but when I put it to server It just keep saying it's loading (Not sure if it's allowed to post links so somebody remove it if it isn't allowed) http://puskice.org/assets/frontend/pacman/index.html

Important note is that server is behind Cloudflare so I was wondering if it could have something to do with it.
Application at link above sometimes works when you hit shift+f5 in chrome, and in firefox it mostly works as expected

Comment: Questions about software installation are not within the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Not wondering about installation, but about Canvas behaviour, and possible bugs when using it with cloudflare. I'm not sure if it's code related, browser or cloudflare related

Answer (score 0):

I opened your site and it appears that your audio files are failing to load.

If you follow the pacman code through, then you'll notice that it displays a loading message (line 1056), and doesn't redraw until after at least one audio file has loaded (line 1082).

but your audio files are 404-ing, so the loaded function is never called.

Comment: So if I disable audio, it should work. Will try to edit code tommorow. Thanks